# Underscore.nest module not working

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I'm not sure whey I'm getting an error when I run this script in the terminal. The error is:

_.nest(data,"name"); TypeError: object is not a function

Here is my script:

```
_ = require('underscore');

_.nest = require('underscore.nest');

var data = [
    {'name' : 'name 1', '0' : 'tag_a', '1' : 'tag_b'},
    {'name' : 'name 2', '0' : 'tag_a', '1' : 'tag_c', '2' : 'tag_b'},
    {'name' : 'name 3', '0' : 'tag_c', '1' : 'tag_a', '2' : 'tag_b'}
];

data = _.nest(data, 'name');

console.log(data);
```

Comment: What is `console.log(_.nest)`? (`console.log(typeof _.nest)`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a "nest" that should be:

```
data = _.nest.nest(data, 'name');
```

Comment: I suspect it rather should be `var _ = require("underscore.nest");`

Comment: well, as per Readme here you have to require Underscore and Underscore Nest https://github.com/iros/underscore.nest#nodejs

Comment: OK, that's odd. It even seems to rely on a global `_` variable.